# The stiffness matrix for a triangle in the finite element mehod

Tags: partial-differential-equations, computational-mathematics, finite-element-method

In Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiffness_matrix under section "Practical assembly of the stiffness matrix" section, it says that:

For example, for piecewise linear elements, consider a triangle with vertices $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3)$, and define the 2×3 matrix
$$D = \begin{bmatrix}x_3 -x_2 & x_1-x_3&x_2-x_1\\
y_3-y_2& y_1-y_3& y_2-y_1
 \end{bmatrix}$$
Then the element stiffness matrix is
$$A^{[k]} = \frac{D^TD}{4 area(T)}$$
I wonder how the above expression, the element stiffness matrix for a triangle, is derived.

Thank you.

Comment: To derive this, you can "just" do all the computations for a general triangle and $P1$ elements and get the resulting expression. This is done e. g. in [his paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1019155918070), namely page 122 and the expression for $G$ there which is the $D$ from Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks, @Korf. That is very helpful. May I ask why equation (11) and the following line about $\bigtriangledown \eta_j(x,y) $ hold?

Comment: That is a nice little trick. You want the basis functions to be linear and 1 in vertex $j$ and 0 in the other two. Determinant is linear in rows/columns, so linearity is checked. Determinant with two same rows is 0 so we have zero in vertices $j+1, j+2$. To get 1 in vertex $j$ we normalize with the determinant in denominator. This line with gradient follows directly from (11) and can be derived by direct computation.